# Using "playn showcase" for eclipse, getting "Could not resolve dependencies" error

Tags: eclipse, playn

I followed the instructions at 
http://0-code.google.com.precise.petronas.com.my/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted
But got an error (see below).

I use the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and I installed the Maven Natives Plugin for Eclipse. And I did the "Run as → Maven test".
By the way, when I use command line mvn test, it works OK.
I want to solve the Eclipse problems. I am really frustrated and need your help.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project playn-showcase-java: Could
>   not resolve dependencies for project
>   com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-java:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to
>   find com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in
>   http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of forplay-legacy has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help
>   1]

Comment: Hi first of all, did  you install a maven > 3.0.3 ? the integrated version in eclipse is 3.0.2 and playN needs 3.0.3.

Comment: Following the exact same GettingStarted guide with Eclipse Juno (Maven 3.0.4 included), so the issue does not seem to be with Maven.

Comment: This answer solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11858227/1464763