# Unable to run playn sample project - compile errors

Tags: playn

I've tried to follow the instructions on the getting started page for playn and run into problems when running the first program java showcase.  I get the following errors when right clicking and running Maven test. Also I get numerous errors in the problem tab of eclipse related to (failure to transfer xxx from yyy) where xxx is some jar file and yyy is a gwt or playn website

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PlayN Showcase Java 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.10/maven-surefire-plugin-2.10.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.10/maven-surefire-plugin-2.10.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.10/maven-surefire-plugin-2.10.pom (11 KB at 47.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.10/surefire-2.10.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.10/surefire-2.10.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.10/surefire-2.10.pom (12 KB at 118.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/20/maven-parent-20.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/20/maven-parent-20.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/20/maven-parent-20.pom (25 KB at 143.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.6/maven-antrun-plugin-1.6.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.6/maven-antrun-plugin-1.6.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.6/maven-antrun-plugin-1.6.pom (5 KB at 52.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/googlecode/playn/playn-showcase-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/com/googlecode/playn/playn-showcase-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/com/googlecode/playn/playn-showcase-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/playn-showcase-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/googlecode/playn/playn-showcase-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/playn-showcase-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/jlayer/tritonus_share/1.0/tritonus_share-1.0.pom
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, no checksums available from the repository for http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/jlayer/tritonus_share/1.0/tritonus_share-1.0.pom
Downloaded: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/jlayer/tritonus_share/1.0/tritonus_share-1.0.pom (462 B at 0.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/com/googlecode/playn/playn-showcase-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/playn-showcase-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Downloading: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/jlayer/mp3spi/1.9.5/mp3spi-1.9.5.jar
Downloading: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/jlayer/tritonus_share/1.0/tritonus_share-1.0.jar
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, no checksums available from the repository for http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/jlayer/mp3spi/1.9.5/mp3spi-1.9.5.jar
Downloaded: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/jlayer/mp3spi/1.9.5/mp3spi-1.9.5.jar (25 KB at 40.9 KB/sec)
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, no checksums available from the repository for http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/jlayer/tritonus_share/1.0/tritonus_share-1.0.jar
Downloaded: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/jlayer/tritonus_share/1.0/tritonus_share-1.0.jar (101 KB at 102.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/googlecode/playn/playn-showcase-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/playn-showcase-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.155s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 07 08:01:22 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/112M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project playn-showcase-java: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-java:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in forplay-legacy (http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

Right click on "playn-showcase" then: Run As -> Maven Install

It should retrieve all dependencies correctly.

Next time you want to launch the sample, you can follow the tutorial procedure:

Right click on "playn-showcase-java" then: Run As -> Maven Test

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the project working, doing 3 things (not sure which is required vs. which I just happen to do on the way to getting it working):
1.  Run Maven Install instead of Maven Test
2.  Run on the playn-showcase instead of playn-showcase-java
3.  Set the java_home directory to the location my SDK was installed (defaulted to a jre directory that did not have a tools.jar).